# Redirect the tail output to a file then stop when match found

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, io-redirection, tail

There is this log file that data coming in is continuous. What I wanted to happen is to tail -f this log file then redirect it to a file with the ff conditions

example of the log files content

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
bbbbbbbbbbbbbbb
ccccccccccccccc
ddddddddddddddd
eeeeeeeeeeeeeee
fffffffffffffff
ggggggggggggggg
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
iiiiiiiiiiiiiii
```

in tailing, I want the redirection to start when it found the first pattern then stop the redirection as well as tailing when I found the second pattern. e.g

I want the redirection starts when it found pattern "ddddddddddddddd" then will stops when it found "hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh" the contents of the file created from redirection should be

```
ddddddddddddddd
eeeeeeeeeeeeeee
fffffffffffffff
ggggggggggggggg
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh
```

In coding I'm thinking of something like this. But I don't have idea how to stop the redirection when it found the second pattern.

```
tail -f logfile > log.tmp
while grep "ddddddddddddddd" log.tmp
do
cat log.tmp > logfile
done
```

Answer (score 4):

This is exactly what [`retail`](https://github.com/mwh/retail) does. `retail` is tail with regular expressions, a tool I wrote for exactly the use case you have here.  In your case, you'd use:

```
retail -f -r ddddddddddddddd -u hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh logfile > log.tmp
```

`-f` is the standard `tail -f` option. `-r` takes a regular expression to use to start the range of lines to include, and `-u` takes a regular expression for it to continue until. It begins at the *last* occurrence of the `-r` pattern and exits after printing the *first* occurrence of the `-u` pattern thereafter.

If you want to start from the first instance of the pattern you can use `-b` in combination with `-r`. Both regular expressions are [EREs](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_04), without any implicit anchoring, but you can use `^` and `$` to anchor the match as usual.

---

You can obtain and build `retail` with:

```
git clone https://github.com/mwh/retail.git
cd retail
./configure
make
make install
```

It installs into `~/.local/bin` by default, but you can change that, or just copy the executable where you want.

---

`retail` is fully [POSIX-compatible](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tail.html), though I don't recommend actually using it as your system `tail`.

Comment: is this a redhat package or debian? how can i install this?

Comment: There are installation instructions between the horizontal rules. As far as I know there are neither Red Hat nor Debian packages.

Comment: can you send me the link and instructions how to install this? TIA

Comment: Look about ten centimetres above your comment, where the grey box is.

Comment: sorry but i'm not allowed to install the git here in the server. is there anyway to download it and install it manually?

Comment: There is a "[download zip](https://github.com/mwh/retail/archive/master.zip)" button on the linked page, or you could download the source on any other machine and transfer it.

Comment: there you go! i just downloaded it thanks!

Comment: @mikeserv: No `-r` at the moment, but maybe sometime. The POSIX compatibility was more of a why-not than anything. It has exactly the options mentioned above plus `-c`.

Comment: nolram, either make that directory or give a different target with `./configure --prefix=...`. Or just copy the executable out to where you want it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `awk`'s range patterns here:

```
tail -f logfile | awk '/ddddddddddddddd/,/hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh/'
```

---

If you need to circumvent the `SIGPIPE` problem you can use `socat` instead of `tail` for the job:

```
socat -u file:logfile,ignoreeof "system:'stdbuf -o0 awk /ddddddddddddddd/,/hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh/'" > logfile.new
```

Comment: You might need an `exit` in the `awk` code to generate SIGPIPE back to the `tail` so that it also stopped

Comment: In that case I would use `socat` for the job.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your demands correct this does what you expect:

```
awk '/ddddddddddddddd/,/hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh/ { print > "excerpt" } 1' infile | tail -f
```

`awk` works as filter on file "infile"; it prints everything in between the given patterns into a file "excerpt", and it also prints every line to standard output, which is then processed by `tail -f` as usual.

In case you want to use it with streamed data:

```
some_process | awk '/ddddddddddddddd/,/hhhhhhhhhhhhhhh/ { print > "excerpt" } 1'  | tail -f
```

(Note: Since `tail -f` is an interactive program it should come, if possible, always last in a pipeline.)

Comment: If the OP is considering `tail -f` at all then it suggests the source file is growing over time. In this situation `awk` would fall off the end of the partially created file and your `tail -f` would never see any more input.

Comment: @roaima; That's why I provided the second variant; don't create the file but pipe data directly from the generating process. If you want the logfile with *all* data anyway persistent then use `tee`: `some_process | tee logfile | awk '...' | tail -f`.

Comment: In neither example does the `tail -f` add any value

Comment: @roaima; Huh? - If you have a long continuously written logfile you want to follow it as it's written. Wasn't that the point of the request?! To explain the (optional) parts: the `tee logfile` is if you want a persistent complete logfile, the `awk` part is to filter the pattern-matched subsection and store it separately on the fly, and the `tail -f` is to watch the log interactively while it's generate.

Comment: Yes exactly! Contrast `for F in `seq 9`; do echo "$F"; sleep 1; done | awk '/4/,/7/' | tail -f` with and without the `tail`. Similarly, to simulate from a growing file, `for F in `seq 9`; do echo "$F"; sleep 1; done >tmp & sleep 1 ; awk '/4/,/7/' tmp | tail -f` also with and without the `tail`

Comment: What does this mean: *since `tail -f` is an interactive program it should come, if possible, always last in a pipeline*? Do you mean `tail -f file | filter` is problematic for some reason? I confess I have little experience w/ `tail -f` use, but I'm confused about why it should be so. It seems to me any reader of `tail`'s pipe should just hang waiting for more input until `tail` `write()`s it. Does `tail` send a `PIPE` signal before it quits or do you mean that a keyboard generated `INT` might fail to reach it perhaps? As I currently understand it, I'm inclined to agree w/ @roaima, though.

Comment: @roaima; the code in your comment is disfunctional as displayed (use `$(...)` instead of the backtics meta-characters, which seems to be the source of the issue). I'll look at the code in your comment later.

Comment: @mikeserv; What I meant is; `tail -f` is (as opposed to plain `tail`) a use of the tool to inspect dynamically the outcome of data on the fly. Subsequent processes (in the pipeline) will always work on incomplete data (or data that is usually not known to be [yet] complete). It's not "problematic", it's rather a conceptual decision! - The way I structured (and decomposed) the tasks (`tee`, `awk`, `tail`) separates the individual parts depending on the intended (sub-)tasks; remove or add any subtask depending on the requirements. - I think it's clearer and cleaner. YMMV.

Comment: OK, but I don't think `tail -f` does anything at all here. if you're just `tail`ing stdin to stdout then why do it at all since `awk`'s stdout is the stdin in the first place? would it not net the same effect if you were to leave it of entirely? it seems `tail -f` will just follow the end of a pipe until `awk` closes it - so why not drop it?